# ASP.NET MVC 5: passing POST data between views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'd like to ask a very simple question from a rookie. I want to pass data from view `Alpha.cshtml`, into controller `HomeController.cs` with action `Beta()`, and then display this data in view `Beta.cshtml`.

Here's my `Alpha.cshtml`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Beta", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    @Html.TextBox("data")
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Here's my `Beta.cshtml`:

```
<p>The submitted value is: @ViewBag.Data</p>
```

And here's my `Beta()` action:

```
public ActionResult Beta()
{
    ViewBag.Data = ???
    return View();
}
```

What do I put in place of the ???

Thanks!

Comment: Not entirely unrelated: it might be usefull to use TempData rather than ViewData/ViewBag

Answer (score 0):

When the form is submitted, all form input fields will be posted to the server. ModelBinding will take care of reading the posted values and supplying them to your action method in the list of parameters.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Beta(string data)
{
    ViewBag.Data = data
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if there are several fields being submitted by the form, rather than just the one data field? Do I have to pass each one as an argument to Beta()?

Comment: You can, or better yet, create an object that has each of those properties so that you'll have the object as the only parameter: `Beta(MyObject data)`. More info: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx